# Kobold2d generates errors after upgraded Xcode to 4.6

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d, xcode4.6

After upgrading my Xcode to 4.6, Kobold2d 2.0.4 generates error as below. Anyone encounter this problem too?

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

CompileC /Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCAnimationExtensions.o kobold2d/cocos2d-ext/CCAnimationExtensions.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wstrict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -I/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/kobold2d-ios.hmap -I/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d -I/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK -I/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/libs/cocos2d-iphone/external/kazmath/include -I/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -include /Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-iOS-bfbcgatlrctdcneqvloiipzyvdrz/Prefix-iOS.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCAnimationExtensions.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCAnimationExtensions.dia -c /Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/cocos2d-ext/CCAnimationExtensions.m -o /Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/Kobold2D-Libraries.build/Debug-iphoneos/kobold2d-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCAnimationExtensions.o

/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/cocos2d-ext/CCAnimationExtensions.m:11:1: error: class 'FIXCATEGORYBUGCCAnimation' defined without specifying a base class [-Werror,-Wobjc-root-class]
FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(CCAnimation)
^
/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/cocos2d-ext/FixCategoryBug.h:15:43: note: expanded from macro 'FIX_CATEGORY_BUG'
#define FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name; @end @implementation FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name; @end
                                          ^
<scratch space>:5:1: note: expanded from macro 'FIXCATEGORYBUG'
FIXCATEGORYBUGCCAnimation
^
note: add a super class to fix this problem
1 error generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

/Users/ernnug/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/<command line>:3:10: '/Users/ernnug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-brplvdgzzqjavebyfesirygztebf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-iOS-gizjrgholmwiqtfonzxtvzvwrkxa/Prefix-iOS.pch' file not found
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply remove all references to FIXCATEGORYBUG. It is no longer needed.

Comment: And how do I remove all references to FIXCATEGORYBUG?

Comment: go to CCAnimationsExtensions.m and remove #import "FixCategoryBug.h"
FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(CCAnimation)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a rundown of the files where I removed FixCategoryBug to correct the issue:

- CCAnimationExtentions.m
- CCDirectorExtensions.m
- CCNodeExtensions.m
- CCSpriteExtensions.m
- NSMutableArray+WeakReferences.m