# Kobold2d and XCode 4.6 Error

Tags: kobold2d, xcode4.6

I had the same issue as [gabrielhilal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155142/gabrielhilal) as see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581605/kobold2d-generates-errors-after-upgraded-xcode-to-4-6). [LearnCocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201863/learncocos2d) posted to remove all references to FIXCATEGORYBUG. My question is how to do this? References from where? My apologies if that is a silly question.

Answer (score 4):

The following files in Kobold2d have to be changed:

FixCategoryBug.h line 15:

from:

```
#define FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name; @end @implementation FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name; @end
```

to:

```
#define FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name : NSObject @end @implementation FIXCATEGORYBUG ## name @end
```

NSMutableArray+WeakReferences.m line 39:

from:

```
#define FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name @end @implementation FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name @end
```

to:

```
#define FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name : NSObject @end @implementation FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name @end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was a lame question. Sorry I'm new. On the off chance someone else sees this then just go to Edit > Find > Find in Workspace. Search for FIXCATEGORYBUG. I commented every #import statement and things worked ok after that.